# python text based game unresolved reference error message

Tags: python

I am writing code for a text based game. I have 8 rooms with 6 items in those rooms except in the start room of Counselor Cabin and Crystal Lake, which is the last room and has the villain.
Below is my coding. For the most part it is correct without many errors except 1 big 1.
I am using pycharm and getting the following error:
UNRESOLVED REFERENCE 'rooms'
This appears on basically every reference of rooms in my code. I believe it has to do with:

```
def main():

     rooms = {
```

at the top of my code.
Can anyone please help me with this?

THANKS!!

```html
def instructions():
    print('*******************************************************************************************')
    print('Welcome to: Friday the 13th Text Based Game')
    print('Move Between Rooms, Collect all 6 items')
    print('Once you have all 6 items navigate to Crystal Lake where you will encounter Jason Voorhees')
    print('Use all 6 items to protect the campers and destroy Jason!')
    print('*******************************************************************************************')
    print('To move between rooms, type: go North, go South, go East, or go West')
    print('To add an item to inventory, type: add "item name"')
    print('You may exit at any time by typing: Exit')
    print('*******************************************************************************************')


# move between rooms and print current room
def move_rooms(current_room, directions, rooms):
    current_room = rooms[current_room][directions]
#    new_room = current_room[directions]
    return current_room


# add item from room and remove from list
def add_item(current_room, directions, rooms, inventory):
    inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])
    del rooms[current_room]['item']


# dictionary of rooms and items
def main():

    rooms = {
        'Counselor Cabin': {'East': 'Campers Cabin', 'South': 'Cafeteria'},
        'Campers Cabin': {'West': 'Counselor Cabin', 'item': 'Flashlight'},
        'Cafeteria': {'North': 'Counselor Cabin', 'East': 'First Aid', 'item': 'Water'},
        'First Aid': {'West': 'Cafeteria', 'South': 'Shower Building', 'item': 'Bandages'},
        'Shower Building': {'North': 'First Aid', 'item': 'Matches'},
        'Supply Storage': {'North': 'Cafeteria', 'South': 'Maintenance Garage', 'item': 'Can of Gas'},
        'Maintenance Garage': {'North': 'Supply Storage', 'East': 'Crystal Lake', 'item': 'Axe'},
        'Crystal Lake': {'West': 'Maintenance Garage'},
    }


# create blank inventory list
inventory = []
# and start
current_room = 'Counselor Cabin'
instructions()

# Last room win or end game
while True:
    if current_room == 'Crystal Lake':
        if len(inventory) == 6:
            print('*******************************************************************************************')
            print('You hit Jason with the Axe and he falls down')
            print('*******************************************************************************************')
            print('You then take the gas and pour it all over Jason')
            print('*******************************************************************************************')
            print('You stirke a match and light Jason on fire......he has been destroyed!')
            print('*******************************************************************************************')
            print('Congratulations!!!' 'You have saved all of the campers!')
            print('Thank you for playing, come back soon!')
            print('*******************************************************************************************')
            break
        else:
            print('*******************************************************************************************')
            print('Jason has found you!')
            print('*******************************************************************************************')
            print('You did not collect all of the items to destroy Jason')
            print('*******************************************************************************************')
            print('Jason slays you with his machete and now he is after the campers!')
            print('*******************************************************************************************')
            print('GAME OVER')
            print('*******************************************************************************************')
            break

# print current room & inventory
    print('*******************************************************************************************')
    print('You are in the', current_room)
    print(inventory)
    print('*******************************************************************************************')
    if current_room != 'Crystal Lake' and 'item' in rooms[current_room].keys():
        print('You have found the {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
    print('*******************************************************************************************')
    directions = input('What direction do you want to go?').title().split()
# move into new room
    if len(directions) >= 2 and move[1] in rooms[current_room].keys():
        current_room = move_rooms(current_room, directions[1], rooms)
        continue
# add to inventory
    elif len(directions[0]) == 3 and directions[0] == 'Add' and ' '.join(directions[1:]) in rooms[current_room]['item']:
        print('You add teh {} to your inventory'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
        print('*******************************************************************************************')
        add_inventory(current_room, directions, rooms, inventory)
        break

# invalid and exit commands
    if directions == 'Exit':
        print('You have chosen to exit the game. Jason has found you and has killed you!')
        print('Thank you for playing, Come back soon!')
        break

    else:
        print('Invalid command, try again!')
        continue


main()
```

Comment: Tabs are VERY important in Python, if you want everything starting with `# create blank inventory list` to be part of `main()` then it needs to be tabbed to the same level as `rooms` currently is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @BeRT2me that it is an indentation problem. Right now the problem is that your `while` loop runs outside of the `main` function, and `rooms` is a variable that is only defined inside that function (and cleared once the function exits). I believe that what you want is:

```
def instructions():
    print('***************************************************************')
    print('Welcome to: Friday the 13th Text Based Game')
    print('Move Between Rooms, Collect all 6 items')
    print('Once you have all 6 items navigate to Crystal Lake where you will encounter Jason Voorhees')
    print('Use all 6 items to protect the campers and destroy Jason!')
    print('*******************************************************************************************')
    print('To move between rooms, type: go North, go South, go East, or go West')
    print('To add an item to inventory, type: add "item name"')
    print('You may exit at any time by typing: Exit')
    print('*******************************************************************************************')


# move between rooms and print current room
def move_rooms(current_room, directions, rooms):
    current_room = rooms[current_room][directions]
    # new_room = current_room[directions]
    return current_room


# add item from room and remove from list
def add_item(current_room, directions, rooms, inventory):
    inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])
    del rooms[current_room]['item']


# dictionary of rooms and items
def main():

    rooms = {
        'Counselor Cabin': {'East': 'Campers Cabin', 'South': 'Cafeteria'},
        'Campers Cabin': {'West': 'Counselor Cabin', 'item': 'Flashlight'},
        'Cafeteria': {'North': 'Counselor Cabin', 'East': 'First Aid', 'item': 'Water'},
        'First Aid': {'West': 'Cafeteria', 'South': 'Shower Building', 'item': 'Bandages'},
        'Shower Building': {'North': 'First Aid', 'item': 'Matches'},
        'Supply Storage': {'North': 'Cafeteria', 'South': 'Maintenance Garage', 'item': 'Can of Gas'},
        'Maintenance Garage': {'North': 'Supply Storage', 'East': 'Crystal Lake', 'item': 'Axe'},
        'Crystal Lake': {'West': 'Maintenance Garage'},
    }


    # create blank inventory list
    inventory = []
    # and start
    current_room = 'Counselor Cabin'
    instructions()

    # Last room win or end game
    while True:
        if current_room == 'Crystal Lake':
            if len(inventory) == 6:
                print('*******************************************************************************************')
                print('You hit Jason with the Axe and he falls down')
                print('*******************************************************************************************')
                print('You then take the gas and pour it all over Jason')
                print('*******************************************************************************************')
                print('You stirke a match and light Jason on fire......he has been destroyed!')
                print('*******************************************************************************************')
                print('Congratulations!!!' 'You have saved all of the campers!')
                print('Thank you for playing, come back soon!')
                print('*******************************************************************************************')
                break
            else:
                print('*******************************************************************************************')
                print('Jason has found you!')
                print('*******************************************************************************************')
                print('You did not collect all of the items to destroy Jason')
                print('*******************************************************************************************')
                print('Jason slays you with his machete and now he is after the campers!')
                print('*******************************************************************************************')
                print('GAME OVER')
                print('*******************************************************************************************')
                break

        # print current room & inventory
        print('*******************************************************************************************')
        print('You are in the', current_room)
        print(inventory)
        print('*******************************************************************************************')
        if current_room != 'Crystal Lake' and 'item' in rooms[current_room].keys():
            print('You have found the {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
        print('*******************************************************************************************')
        directions = input('What direction do you want to go? ').title().split()

        # move into new room
        if len(directions) >= 2 and directions[1] in rooms[current_room].keys():
            current_room = move_rooms(current_room, directions[1], rooms)
            continue
        # add to inventory
        elif len(directions[0]) == 3 and directions[0] == 'Add' and ' '.join(directions[1:]) in rooms[current_room]['item']:
            print('You added the {} to your inventory'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
            print('*******************************************************************************************')
            add_item(current_room, directions, rooms, inventory)

        # invalid and exit commands
        if directions[0] == 'Exit':
            print('You have chosen to exit the game. Jason has found you and has killed you!')
            print('Thank you for playing, Come back soon!')
            break

        else:
            print('Invalid command, try again!')
            continue


main()
```

I've fixed the indentation, and some other minor bugs, above.

The game seems cool. (I would recommend showing the possible next directions next to each room though.)

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your input. I did fix it in the early hours this morning. It was for sure an indentation issue. I have corrected it and it seems to work just fine now with lexx errors reporting in PyCharm. I have also changed the code so you actually have to add inventory. The last piece that I have to figure out is when the player types Exit, then it prints some text lines then exits the game

Comment: @ATony......I did not realize you had corrected my exit game option as well. THANKS!!!! That was my missing piece to finish this.

Comment: If this answered your question, please remember to select it as the answer so that the question is marked accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```html
def instructions():
    print('*******************************************************************************************')
    print('Welcome to: Friday the 13th Text Based Game')
    print('Move Between Rooms, Collect all 6 items')
    print('Once you have all 6 items navigate to Crystal Lake where you will encounter Jason Voorhees')
    print('Use all 6 items to protect the campers and destroy Jason!')
    print('*******************************************************************************************')
    print('To move between rooms, type: go North, go South, go East, or go West')
    print('To add an item to inventory, type: add "item name"')
    print('You may exit at any time by typing: Exit')
    print('*******************************************************************************************')


# move between rooms and print current room
def move_rooms(current_room, directions, rooms):
    current_room = rooms[current_room][directions]
    return current_room


# add item from room and remove from list
def add_inventory(current_room, rooms, inventory):
    inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])
    del rooms[current_room]['item']


# dictionary of rooms and items
def main():

    rooms = {
        'Counselor Cabin': {'East': 'Campers Cabin', 'South': 'Cafeteria'},
        'Campers Cabin': {'West': 'Counselor Cabin', 'item': 'Flashlight'},
        'Cafeteria': {'North': 'Counselor Cabin', 'East': 'First Aid', 'South': 'Supply Storage', 'item': 'Water'},
        'First Aid': {'West': 'Cafeteria', 'South': 'Shower Building', 'item': 'Bandages'},
        'Shower Building': {'North': 'First Aid', 'item': 'Matches'},
        'Supply Storage': {'North': 'Cafeteria', 'South': 'Maintenance Garage', 'item': 'Gas'},
        'Maintenance Garage': {'North': 'Supply Storage', 'East': 'Crystal Lake', 'item': 'Axe'},
        'Crystal Lake': {'West': 'Maintenance Garage'}
    }


# create blank inventory list
    inventory = []
# and start
    current_room = 'Counselor Cabin'
    instructions()

# Last room win or end game
    while True:
        if current_room == 'Crystal Lake':
            if len(inventory) == 6:
                print(current_room)
                print('You have found Jason at Crystal Lake')
                print('*******************************************************************************************')
                print('You hit Jason with the Axe and he falls down')
                print('*******************************************************************************************')
                print('You then take the gas and pour it all over Jason')
                print('*******************************************************************************************')
                print('You strike a match and light Jason on fire......he has been destroyed!')
                print('*******************************************************************************************')
                print('Congratulations!!!' 'You have saved all of the campers!')
                print('Thank you for playing, come back soon!')
                print('*******************************************************************************************')
                break
            else:
                print('*******************************************************************************************')
                print('Jason has found you!')
                print('*******************************************************************************************')
                print('You did not collect all of the items to destroy Jason')
                print('*******************************************************************************************')
                print('Jason slays you with his machete and now he is after the campers!')
                print('*******************************************************************************************')
                print('GAME OVER')
                print('*******************************************************************************************')
                break

# print current room & inventory
        print('*******************************************************************************************')
        print('You are in the', current_room)
        print(inventory)
        print('*******************************************************************************************')
        if current_room != 'Crystal Lake' and 'item' in rooms[current_room].keys():
            print('You have found the {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
        print('*******************************************************************************************')
        directions = input('Do you want to add item or go direction?').title().split()

# move into new room
        if len(directions) >= 2 and directions[1] in rooms[current_room].keys():
            current_room = move_rooms(current_room, directions[1], rooms)
            continue
# add to inventory
        elif len(directions[0]) == 3 and directions[0] == 'Add' and ' ' \
                ''.join(directions[1:]) in rooms[current_room]['item']:
            print('You add the {} to your inventory'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
            print('*******************************************************************************************')
            add_inventory(current_room, rooms, inventory)
            continue

# exit commands
        if directions[0] == 'Exit':
            print('You have chosen to exit the game. Jason has found you and has killed you!')
            print('Thank you for playing, Come back soon!')
            break
# invalid commands
        else:
            print('Invalid command, try again!')
            continue


main()
```

Comment: This is what my final code looks like. Feel free to try it out. I might try to make a text based Jason mask and add it into the game yet. But thanks to everyone who led me in the right direction!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).